# Problems accessing values in forms with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, wordpress, geocoding

I'm writing a tool that takes a user-inputted address and converts it to a geolocation for GoogleMaps' api.

**Edit:** I do want to submit the form data, though.. I think. I'm not sure if submitting the form is necessary, but the end result is that it should generate a post in wordpress containing the `title`, `address`, and `geo` values.

The method called by the submit button works correctly if the `<form></form>` tags are removed. If the `<form>` tags are around the form, the method will still be called but it won't geocode anything. Did I set up my form incorrectly?

Here is the form:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$address = $_POST['address'];

$new_post = array(
     'post_title' => $title,
     'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_type' => 'post',
     'address' => $address,
     'geo' => $geo,
  );

$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

update_post_meta($post_id, 'address', $address, true);
update_post_meta($post_id, 'geo', $geo, true);  

?>

<?php get_header()?>

    <label>Event: </label><input id="title"  type="text"/>
    <label>Address: </label><input id="address"  type="text"/>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:500px"></div><br/>
    <label>latitude: </label><input id="latitude" type="text"/><br/>
    <label>longitude: </label><input id="longitude" type="text"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" id="compute" onClick="getCoordinates()" value="lets try it">

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>


<?php get_footer()?>
```

Here is the relevant function:

```
function getCoordinates() {
//variables are set up on page initialization   
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': $('#address').val() }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        alert ('latitude: ' + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + ' longitude: ' + results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        $('#latitude').val( results[0].geometry.location.lat() ) ;
        $('#longitude').val( results[0].geometry.location.lng() ) ;
        $geo =  results[0].geometry.location.lat() + "," + results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location

      });
      }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the input button from type="submit" to type="button" and leave the form tags off.  You only use a form with a submit button inside when you want to actually submit the form, not perform a javascript only action.

Answer (score 0):

When the  elements are being used, it's a good idea to bind this geocode function to the [onsubmit event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp) for that .

```
<form onsubmit="getCoords()">
...fields...
</form>
<script>
function getCoords(){

geocoder.makeALongRequest("some","params",function(result,data,xhr){
  alert("this is the request callback");
  });

//Always return false in the onsubmit event if you want to stop the browser from trying to POST anything
return false;
}
```

Comment: well I shouldn't have gone to the bathroom mid-answer apparently. Oh well.